# Hypergeometric Function and Elliptic Integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

In the wiki [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral), complete elliptic integrals of first and second kind are related to the Hypergeometric function via:
$$
K(k)=\frac{\pi}{2} \mathstrut_{2}F_{1}(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};1;k^{2})\\
E(k)=\frac{\pi}{2} \mathstrut_{2}F_{1}(\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2};1;k^{2})
$$

But when evaluate the following command in Mathematica (ver.12):

```
Pi/2 Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, 1/2, 1, k^2]
```

I get: `EllipticK[k^2]`

The same thing happens for $ \mathstrut_{2}F_{1}(\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2};1;k^{2})$
as well. I get `EllipticE[k^2]` instead of `EllipticE[k]`.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you are missing is that the Wiki page you refer to uses the *modulus* convention for elliptic integrals, while *Mathematica* uses the *parameter* convention. I had ranted about this at great length [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/108659), and see also [the docs](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/MathematicalFunctions.html#7229).

That's why you need to be careful about using any formula you see from other references in general; you need to make sure the convention it uses is the same (or can be converted to) the convention *Mathematica* uses.