# Is EllipticK defined correctly in Mathematica?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

I needed to calculate

```
F[a]=Integrate[1/(Sqrt[x^2+1]Sqrt[x^2+a^2]),{x,0,Infinity}]
```

so I fed it to Mathematica.  The result I got was:

```
ConditionalExpression[Sqrt[1/a^2] Sqrt[a^2] EllipticK[1 - a^2], Re[a^2] > 0]
```

In my case, `a` is real and >=1, so I was happy, but also curious, as I was not familiar
with the function.  I looked up the function in Wikipedia, and found:
$$
K(k) = \int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}\sqrt{1-k^2 t^2}}\, \mathrm{d} t
$$
With that result I realized that if I do a variable substitution `t=x/Sqrt[x^2+a^2]`
manually, I can solve the integral myself. So I did, and got:

```
F[a]=(1/a)*Integrate[1/(Sqrt[1-t^2]Sqrt[1-(1-1/a^2)*t^2]),{t,0,1}]
```

which
equals `(1/a)*K(Sqrt[1-1/a^2])` according to Wikipedia!  So not at all
the same as what Mathematica told me.

I raised the issue with Mathematica support, and they pointed out that if I do:

```
Integrate[1/(Sqrt[x^2+1]Sqrt[x^2+a^2]),x,0,Infinity},Assumptions->a>0]
```

it
would work.  So I did and got:
`EllipticK[1 - 1/a^2]/a`
So at least Mathematica now got the factor `1/a` right, but the answer was
still wrong according to Wikipedia.  In addition I would have never used
the `Assumption`, since the original answer said it was valid if `Re[a^2] > 0`!

I still argued that according to Wikipedia (which I trust a lot) the
answer should be `(1/a)*EllipticK[Sqrt[1-1/a^2]]`, but they did not seem tocar e.  So I checked an authority: Handbook of Mathematical Functions With Formulas, Graphs, and Mathematical Tables, edited by Milton Abramowitz and Irene A. Stegun, (1972) and found ((17.3.1 on page 590):

```
K[m]=Integrate[1/(Sqrt[1-t^2]Sqrt[1-m*t^2]),{t,0,1}].
```

So it seems that Mathematica's definition of `EllipticK` is right and
Wikipedia's definition is wrong?  Is that the right conclusion?  Should I raise this in Wikipedia?  I still claim that the original Mathematica
answer is wrong, but am frustrated by the lack of interest by Mathematica
support (Case #5061397)

Comment: The *Wolfram Language* definition differs slightly from ususal mathematical definitions. Read carefully documentation of `EllipticK`.  Does this answer your question? [Hypergeometric Function and Elliptic Integral](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/229887/hypergeometric-function-and-elliptic-integral)

Comment: Mathematica follows Abramowitz and Stegun "Handbook of Mathematical Functions" convention  for elliptic integrals which is different from what J.D.Jackson for example follows.  Neither are wrong, just different conventions.  You need to learn how to convert between them.

Comment: Modulus k stems from $k^2 sin^2 \phi$ and is a length. But all resulting Taylor series depend on $k^2$ only, so in numeric analysis and computer aproximation Abramowitz/Stegun took $m=k^2$ as parameter, a rather catastrophical decision, because all elliptic functions are analytic in both variables $z,k$. The online NIST handbook has returned to Jacobis original k-world. The CAS implementations suffer by pattern matching with m_ that cannot distinguish $k, -k$. This is an important point because the underlying $\text{EllipticTheta}$  obbey the diffusion equation with k as time variable.